# How do i edit a specific part of a text file in free pascal?

Tags: freepascal

Just as what the title says, how do i do this? I know that the append command adds text to the end of the file but i don't want to do that nor rewrite the entire text file. I just want to edit a specific part of a text file.

Here's my scenario:

I have different lines of data in a text file, what i'm trying to do is to edit a specific line into a user input. What i already have coded down is finding the line to be edited, and then a user input with the data to change on the line and everything works all fine without problems, however i am completely stumped on what i do to change the data from the text file to user input.

Edit: After frustratingly playing around for a while here's what i've come up to, but it doesn't work, error 106.

```
 If s = 'N' Then
  Begin
    Writeln();
    Writeln('Please enter the correct data');
    Append(sf);
    Readln(sData);
    Writeln(sf, sData);
    Close(sf);
  End;
```

Also to note, i do not have the file close before this block of code but i do have an EOF to stop the previous code from having unneeded looping before breaking, i close the file at the end of this code and again in another block. Either way the file closes but i only get the error with those block.

Comment: Load the entire file. Modify the part that needs to be modified. Save the file again.

Comment: Not writing the entire text file limits your options to pretty much using binary mode, opening the file in Read/Write mode, reading lines manually (i.e., by parsing end-of-line delimiters [CR/LF, LF, or CR depending on OS] while keeping track of your position in the file), and once your target is found, `Seek`ing to the beginning of that line, and writing out your modified line.  But consider issues if new line is either shorter (pad with blanks OK?) or longer than the original.  Longer replacement lines will have you rewrite at least the part of file from first change to end of file.

Comment: As @David said, you should read the entire file. This is very easy with `TStringList.LoadFromFile`.  You can then search and modify any line you like and save the result with `TStringList.SaveToFile`. Anything else is much more complicated, as tonydpmtr's comment explains.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "change the data from the text file to user input"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, using the TStringList procedure my program works the way i want it to.

What i did was load the file with TStringList.LoadFile, and because the data i'm searching through it has a fixed pattern so i was able to search through and indexing through the file with a fixed index (i.e. Index = Index + 3), removed the indexed line in the data file and inserted the new data.